# How to define schema for JSON records with timestamp (from Kafka) using (Py)Spark Structured Streaming? - null values shown

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

The issue is that I am getting `null` values after reading Kafka messages with PySpark.

I use Spark 2.3.1 / Scala 2.11.12

My code:

```
allData = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "mysql.login") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()

df = allData.selectExpr("cast(value as string)", "timestamp", "topic" )

detailSchema = StructType() \
    .add("username", StringType()) \
    .add("login_time", DateType())

df2 = df.select(from_json(col('value'), detailSchema).alias('data'), 'timestamp', 'topic')

writeStream3 = df2 \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime= '4 seconds') \
    .format('console') \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .start()

writeStream3.awaitTermination()
```

The messages read with `kafka-console-consumer.sh` are as follows:

```
$ kafka-console-consumer.sh \
    --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 \
    --topic mysql.login \
    --from-beginning
{"username":"hello kitty","login_time":1572866627000}
{"username":"chitara","login_time":1572867234000}
{"username":"hello kitty","login_time":1572868094000}
```

However, when I try to read the messages I can't see the value. It appears as `null` after the following line:

```
df2 = df.select(from_json(col('value'), detailSchema).alias('data'), 'timestamp', 'topic')
```

The output from my code is:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|               value|           timestamp|      topic|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|{"username":"hell...|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|{"username":"chit...|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|{"username":"hell...|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|{"username":"leon...|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|{"username":"chit...|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
...

+----+--------------------+-----------+
|data|           timestamp|      topic|
+----+--------------------+-----------+
|null|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|null|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|null|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|null|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
|null|2019-11-12 13:55:...|mysql.login|
...

+--------+-----+
|username|count|
+--------+-----+
|    null|  242|
+--------+-----+
```

I think that the issue is related to the parsing that's why I see `null` values after `from_json` function. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `TimestampType` for the `login_time`.

---

Since `login_time` is a timestamp you should use a proper type, e.g. `TimestampType` or `LongType`.

From the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json):

> Returns `null`, in the case of an unparseable string.

That's exactly what you get from `from_json` since the schema does not match the input rows.